# Magento 1.9: Product Export all categories in single line

Tags: magento-1.9, importexport

Single product has multiple categories. Within CSV Export file only one category is listed. Does anyone know why only one category is exported?

I need an export that has all categories listed by single product. How can I achieve that?

Now:

```
sku,_store,_attribute_set,_type,_category,_root_category,_product_websites
5108,,Default,simple,"Beauty/Bad",Pflege,base
5109,,Default,simple,"Beauty/Bad",Pflege,base
```

What i need is something like this:

```
sku,_store,_attribute_set,_type,_category,_root_category,_product_websites
5108,Default,simple,"Beauty/Bad;"Beauty/Küche";"Beauty/Pflege",Pflege,base
5109,Default,simple,"Beauty/Bad;"Beauty/Küche";"Beauty/Pflege",Pflege,base
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make a file at magento root folder and export all sku's and their all categories:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
define('MAGENTO_ROOT', getcwd());
$mageFilename = MAGENTO_ROOT . '/app/Mage.php';
require_once $mageFilename;
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
Mage::app();
$products = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getCollection();
$products->addAttributeToSelect('category_ids');
$products->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1); //optional for only enabled products
$products->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4); //optional for products only visible in catalog and search
$fp        = fopen('exports.csv', 'w');
$csvHeader = array(
    "sku",
    "category_ids",
    "category_name"
);
fputcsv($fp, $csvHeader, ",");
$cat_name  = array();
$cat_array = array();
$cat       = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $sku         = $product->getSku();
    $categoryIds = implode('|', $product->getCategoryIds()); //change the category separator if needed
    $cat_name    = array();
    $cat_array   = $product->getCategoryIds();
    //print_r($cat_array);
    for ($k = 0; $k < count($cat_array); $k++) {
        $id = $cat_array[$k];
        $cat->load($id);
        $cat_name[] = $cat->getName();
    }
    $_cate_name = implode('|', $cat_name);
    fputcsv($fp, array(
        $sku,
        $categoryIds,
        $_cate_name
    ), ",");
}
fclose($fp);
?>
```